# How do I turn a set of equations into a vector

Tags: vector

That's it. I have a set of equations made up in Desmos. What I need to now know is how to turn that into a vector graphic - which, from memory are described using equations.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise what applications do you want to use and what is a sample of those equations. Drawing a vector version of equations is quite easy but quite much hinges on the particular details.

Comment: The "equations" used to describe vector contents are not the same kind as "equations as in a maths book" (oh ... unless the book is *about* those equations, of course). The contents of a vector file are much more like an annotated list of coordinates.

Comment: @usr2564301 yes they are, just piece vise defined. But that's not what OP asks.

Comment: @joojaa: but there are only a small handful of equations used to represent vector graphics – point, line, ellipse, curve. The *equations* are not stored in a (regular type of) vector file. Desmos appears to be the kind of application where they *are*, and it takes a dedicated renderer to view them.

Comment: @usr2564301 no it doesn't . Nearly any graphing package on the planet can do this. Hell ii can do this in illustrator and inkscape too

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid this answer is very long and possibly less than helpful because OP didn't scope their needs! With same effort i could have solved the real problem directly the way that made most sense, too late now.

The graphic in desmos.com is vector drawing. Its just done by a canvas element you could just listen to all canvas calls and dump that into svg or postscript (canvas vectors is almost exactly postscript). But im not going to do that because it wold take an extra 15 minutes i dont have.

If we take [this scene as a example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tw5xhfgmxa). So the question then becomes what software would plot:

(t + t cos(t),t + t * sin(t)) and (t - t cos(t),t + t - sin(t)) in range -10 to 10

A lot few them in fact.

- Mathamatica applications like:

  - Mathematica (you could coerce it to accept tex if you wanted)
  - Maple
  - ...
- Graphing applications
- Scientific apps
- Etc etc.

I counted a whopping 32 apps on my computer that could do this with no fuss.
Mathematica can if asked export that into SVG, EPS, WMF or PDF as segmented line graphs. So heres the thing in Mathematica:

[image]

Mathematica is nice because it understands everything desmos does. And more. But its very expensive (unless you use it on raspberry pi then its free!)

Now nearly any graphing app can do this for here is a python numpy+matplotlib example and it looks almost exactly like one in matlab:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

# Prepare arrays x, y, z
t= np.linspace(-10, 10, 200)

x = t + t * np.cos(t) // this is equation one
y = t + t * np.sin(t)

x2 = t - t * np.cos(t) // and this is two
y2 = t - t * np.sin(t)

ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot(x2, y2)

ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Again the viewer just exports SVG or WPS if you need and its vector. In matlab its also possible but a bit more complicated.

[image]

Now that covers the mainstream applications.

You can also do this in a vector editor like Illustrator and Inkscape directly. Im going to use illustrator since i dont have Inkscape installed but it too has a parametric graphing tool. Im using [jooGraphFunction](https://bitbucket.org/joojaa/jooillustratorscripts/src) script (made by me, yes).

[image]

The reason this script is made is that i often needed curves that are smooth controllable number of spans, so this sidesteps, the need to inaccurately fit a spline trough the points. And that covers the wonderful world of evaluating two expressions in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

The written equations, when copied from Desmos and pasted to elsewhere, are made of some unknown math formula description language. It's possible that some other program accepts them as is or with little modifications. That can be your way to regenerate the creations in more usable format- both equations and the graphs - without retyping the equations. Retyping them in another program shouldn't be a problem, if you have written those equations and understand them.

Unfortunately I do not read, write nor speak well math equations nor their description languages, so any details are beyond the scope of this answer.

Desmos exports the graphs in following formats:

- link to www.desmos.com, even a code snippet to insert it as an external object to your web page or other document
- bitmap image, format=PNG
- PDF

PDF unfortunately is a container for a bitmap image, opening it in Illustrator is useless. It needs plenty of clipping mask eliminations and finally you have the same as importing the PNG.

In illustrator you can trace the graph. The same is possible in Inkscape, but in Illustrator you can get your curve as  a stroke, not as a filled area. If you export the graph 2 times: once with the coordinate system suppressed and once with all parts along, you can trace the curve separately and use the other image as a model to redraw manually the coordinates. You can get good quality vector image without redrawing the curve, too.

Tracing the coordinate system gives poor results.

Here's an example tracing in Inkscape.

[image]

In the left is the original bitmap. In the right there's the traced result. Tracing = stacked colors, only 3 colors are used, no automatic smoothing. To show it's vector, the curve color is changed to blue. NOTE: it's not a curve, it's a filled area.

The curve and the coordinate axles seem to be solid, the auxiliary lines are weak and the numbers are just about readable. High zoom reveals unwanted spikes at the cossings with the coordinate lines.

If you trace in Inkscape the curve-only version separately and draw manually the coordinates, the result can have high quality. Do not expect any clevereness in the places where a curve crosses itself or another curve. It will have unwanted spikes. They can be fixed manually with node editing. That's a lot of work in complex cases.

Inkscape has a tool for making parametric math curves. Check, if it can produce your graphs. It's found from Extensions > Render > parametric curve.

Comment: Its TeX markup. A lot of mathematics software reads it as it is